# Why ClientId and UserId is NULL ASP.NET CORE 5.0 MVC

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I debug my application and I see that ClientId and UserId is recognize as NULL.
Every User has ClientId which represent which `User` belongs `Client`

[image]

After User has been logged in with creditencial (email and pass) he/she should be able to submit ticket.
In Ticket Index View as Admin should be able to see which `User` submit ticket and what is his/her `Client`
I am not expert in this field and try to understand where I made mistake.
When I check database I see that this field is not populated and it show `NULL`

[image]

I just start learning and it is a little bit confusing me and have no idea where I made mistake.
SO far what I did in my controller is :

```
   [Area("Manager")]
    [Authorize(Roles = SD.Role_Admin + "," + SD.Role_Manager)]
    public class TicketController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfwork;

        public TicketController(IUnitOfWork unitOfwork)
        {
            _unitOfwork = unitOfwork;
        }


        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Upsert(int? Id)
        {

            TicketVM ticketVM = new TicketVM()
            {
                Ticket = new Ticket(),                
                TicketTypeList = _unitOfwork.TicketType.GetAll().Select(i => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = i.Name,
                    Value = i.Id.ToString()
                })
            };

            if (Id == null)
            {
                return View(ticketVM);
            }


            ticketVM.Ticket = _unitOfwork.Ticket.Get(Id.GetValueOrDefault());

           

            if (ticketVM.Ticket == null)
            {
                NotFound();
            }
            return View(ticketVM);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Upsert(TicketVM ticketVM)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (ticketVM.Ticket.Id == 0)
                {
                    ticketVM.Ticket.Status = TicketStatus.Otvoren.ToString();
                   _unitOfwork.Ticket.Add(ticketVM.Ticket);
                }
                else
                {
                    _unitOfwork.Ticket.Update(ticketVM.Ticket);
                }
                _unitOfwork.Save();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(ticketVM);
        }

        public IActionResult Details(int? Id)
        {
            TicketVM ticketVM = new TicketVM()
            {
                Ticket = _unitOfwork.Ticket.Get(Id.GetValueOrDefault())
            };

            if (Id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ticketVM.Ticket == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(ticketVM);
        }


        #region API CALLS
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetAll()
        {
            
            var obj = _unitOfwork.Ticket.GetAll(includeProperties: "TicketType,Client,ApplicationUser");
            return Json(new { data = obj });
        }

        #endregion

    }
```

And here is my `TicketModel`

```
public class Ticket
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Opis")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Datum i vrijeme slanja")]
        public DateTime DateAndTime { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

        [Display(Name = "Datum i vrijeme zavrsetka")]
        public DateTime Answered { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Vrsta tiketa")]
        public int TicketTypeID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("TicketTypeID")]
        public virtual TicketType TicketType { get; set; }

        public string UserId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

        public int? ClientId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ClientId")]
        public virtual Client Client { get; set; }


        public string Status { get; set; } = TicketStatus.Otvoren.ToString();


    }
```

I assume I need assign `UserId` and `ClientId` somewhere in controller but have no idea how. I try to google and try to find some solution but have no idea what to look at.
I would be very thankfull if someone can guide me and tell me how to solve this issues since I am begginer and I don't have much experience with this.

Cheers guys  !

**UPDATE**

I add `ViewModel` and in VM I add

```
public class TicketVM
    {
        public Ticket Ticket { get; set; }

        public Client Client { get; set; }

        public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

    }
```

And In Controller I initialize `VM`

```
TicketVM ticketVM = new TicketVM()
            {
                Ticket = new Ticket(),
                TicketTypeList = _unitOfwork.TicketType.GetAll().Select(i => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = i.Name,
                    Value = i.Id.ToString()
                }),
                ApplicationUser = new ApplicationUser(),
                Client = new Client()
            };
```

**Startup.cs**

```
 public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();
            services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser,IdentityRole>().AddDefaultTokenProviders()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
            services.AddSingleton<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
            services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
            services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddMvc(o =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                o.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            });

            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = $"/Identity/Account/Login";
                options.LogoutPath = $"/Identity/Account/Logout";
                options.AccessDeniedPath = $"/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    //pattern: "{area=Manager}/{controller=Ticket}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                    pattern: "{area=Manager}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
```

**Login.cs**

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class LoginModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly ILogger<LoginModel> _logger;

    public LoginModel(SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager, 
        ILogger<LoginModel> logger,
        UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public InputModel Input { get; set; }

    public IList<AuthenticationScheme> ExternalLogins { get; set; }

    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

    [TempData]
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    public class InputModel
    {
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    }

    public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ErrorMessage);
        }

        returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");

        // Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);

        ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

        ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");

        ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
    
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
            }
            if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
            }
            if (result.IsLockedOut)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                return Page();
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return Page();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is credential, do you use identity or other authentication? When the user logs in, the userid should be saved in HttpContext.User. But in your code, where do you get the id?

Comment: Yes I use Identity. I didn't get any `Id` and don't use `HttpContext`

Comment: What should I write in case to use `HttpContext.User` ?

Comment: If it is authorized successfully, the claims should be saved in HttpContext.User, but what content in your HttpContext.User?

Comment: What do you mean by `content in your HttpContext.User?`

Comment: Are there any claims in HttpContext.User?

Comment: Nope, I didn't include anything

Comment: Do you put some claims when you generate the token?

Comment: Yes, I include it. I use `Identity`.

Comment: Can you share some code of generating the token and the configuration in startup?

Comment: I add startup.cs class. If you need more source code please let me know

Comment: How do you handle the login layer, can you share the code? this action method `Identity/Account/Login`.

Comment: I added Login.cs class.

Comment: In the login code, you didn't use the IdentityUser, so it could have no user infomation in HttpContext.User. When user log in, you can query the user information and save it into IdentityUser, and use this: `var login=await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(identityUser, "123abc", true,false);`.

Comment: Where should I include this code ? In `Login.cs` ?

Comment: I have this peac of code 
`var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);`

Comment: Edit this, because it could only provide the email and password, the userid will be not obtained in HttpContext.user.

Comment: I get error message
`IdentityUser' is a type, which is not valid in the given context`

Comment: The user model inherit the IdentityUser.

Comment: Yes, `ApplicationUser` is inherited by `IdentityUser`

Comment: But you need to use this in `_signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229552/discussion-between-unknowuser-and-karney).